# EF4 c# updating nested object in 1:n

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an nested EF object hanging on its parent. It has 1:n relationship

[parent]-[n..child]

the nested object child is dynamic and will be updated through GUI.

i have problem to updating it on database.

**Error message:** *An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.*

this is question is 2nd version. i made a correction on if block for deciding preExist

Thanks in advance for your help

sittingduck

Update on Main

```
void MainUpdate
{
    var context = new FamilyEntities();
    parent = getParentFromGui();
    parent.UpdateRelatedEntities(context);
    context.dispose();

}
```

the object parent was updated in Gui

```
parent getParentFromGui()
{
    parent myParent = parentBindingSource.DataSource as parent;
    foreach(child c in childrenBindingSource)
    {
        myParent.children.Add(c);
    }
    return myParent
}
```

Modified UpdateRelatedEntities

```
public static void UpdateRelatedEntities(this parent entity, FamilyEntities context)
    {
        if (entity == null) return;


        var res = context.parent.Where(x => x.uid_parent == entity.uid_parent);
        var rec = res.FirstOrDefault();

        context.parent.Attach(rec);
        context.parent.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);                                 

        foreach (var c in entity.children)
        {
            bool preExist = context.children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.child_uid == c.child_uid);
            if (preExist != null)
            {                
                context.children.Attach(obj);
                context.children.ApplyCurrentValues(c);
            }
            else
            {                    
                // This Part throw ERROR 
                context.children.AddObject(c);
            }
        }            

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Tx alot!

Comment: What's the context.shaft_section? Does this garanties that the child isn't in the children collection?

Comment: ups sorry, it should be childrend. Thanks for correction

Comment: Now you are checking if a collection equals an item in the collection. This should always be false. Something like context.children.Any(x => x.child_uid == c.child_uid) should probably work

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what *context.shaft_section* is, but logically you have a problem with your code: you don't actually check if element exists in context.children, your *isExist* comes from some other check.

This is prone to errors like the one you have.

*After edit*

And now you're just comparing collection to an element:
context.children.Equals(c)
always FALSE

*After second edit*
This line:

```
context.parent.Attach(rec);
```

attaches object or object graph (meaning - all the children) to context (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx)).
Thus, all your children already belong to context when you are trying to do

```
context.children.AddObject(c);
```

Hence the error - you are trying to add same object twice.

Comment: Oh! I'm too late with my comment

Comment: No it doesn't work the problem is i cannot add an object context.children.AddObject(c);

Comment: Hold on. Where does *parent entity* come from, the database?
If so, chances are that it's existing children, are already included in *context*.

And if c in entites is actually an empty table in DB, there is one more thing to check - make sure that relationships are actually valid and single parent does not suddenly map to all of the rows in that child table

Comment: I've edited my answer base on you post edit.
This line:

    context.parent.Attach(rec);

attaches object or object graph (meaning - all the children) to context

Comment: yes indeed, parent comes from database. At the beginning parent doesn't have any children. GUI will add some. Update will actualize child table. Thanks for the explanation, make sense to me now. Would you explain me your last sentence please? how should update my child table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
foreach (var c in entity.children)
{
    var preexistingChildren = context.children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.child_uid == c.child_uid)
    if (preexistingChildren != null)
    {
        context.children.Attach(obj);
        context.children.ApplyCurrentValues(c);
    }
    else
    {                    
        // ERROR
        context.children.AddObject(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, there is no existing obect c in entites (empty table) but it keep throwing the errror message